# Postgrest function errors

Tags: android, supabase, postgrest

I'm having some issues constructing some functions using postgrest for my senior capstone.

to my understanding the following should work to delete a category connected to a supabase database. (In this context a category is an object with a name and an arraylist of items. items in turn are objects with an ID number, name, price, categoryId and organizationID)

```
override suspend fun deleteCategory(id: Int) {
withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
     postgrest["category"]
        .delete
            {
             eq("id", id)
        }
        .execute()

    }

}
```

however execute is being thrown as a unresolved reference

as well for the update of a category name to my understanding this should work

```
override suspend fun updateCategory(name: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            postgrest["category"]
                    .update()
                    .set("name", name)
                    .execute()
        }
    }
```

But set is being thrown as an unresolved reference as well.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Also if this is not a good way to achieve what i'm trying to do, please let me know. Always eager to learn how to do these better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation, you will notice that there is no `.execute()` call on the Kotlin library for Supabase.

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/kotlin/delete

You should be able to delete your data with code something like this:

```kotlin
supabase.from("category").delete {
    filter {
        eq("id", id)
    }
}
```